# Can you rearrange rows in sql tables accodring to a custom logic?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I've been trying to change the order of rows according to my own logic.

Let's say I have a set of numbers from 1 to 4. If the rows have n entries of different values from 1 to 4 and I want to rearrange all the rows such that I have only rows with 4 at the top followed by a grouped combination of two 2's and a 1, followed by the 3's.

How can it be done using Sql server?

```
ID  ROWS   --> ID  NEW ORDER  
--  ----       --  ---------
 A   1          G    4
 B   1          G    4
 C   2          G    4
 C   2          G    4
 D   2          C    2
 D   2          C    2
 E   2          A    1 
 E   2          E    2
 F   3          E    2
 F   3          B    1
 F   3          D    2
 G   4          D    2
 G   4          F    3
 G   4          F    3
 G   4          F    3
```

Code till now:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
ORDER BY 
CASE 
     WHEN ROW = 4 THEN '1'
     WHEN ROW  = 1 THEN '2'
     WHEN ROW  = 2 THEN '3'
     WHEN ROW  = 3 THEN '4'
END ASC
```

Comment: (1) Yes, you can do this in SQL.  (2) This is an extremely arcane ordering.  Can you explain more about the use-case?

Comment: What happens if the number of rows with `2` aren't double that of `1`? Where does `5` or `0` go, if they can exist? If this is just an arbitrary list, why not store the ordering in a separate column and simply not display it?

Comment: I've used Order by with case so far but im unable to think of a way to actually move the rows i need to.

Comment: @Larnu we assume we always have the same number of rows as tthe number. Also when we have more 2's than 1's or the otherway around, the excess rows would displayed after the (2 + 1) combination.

Comment: Show us those attempts in your question, @VrajeshManiRaja . WE know you would have had to use `ORDER BY`, that's the only way you can achieve the ordering of a result set in SQL Server.

Comment: *"we assume we always have the same number of rows as tthe number"* SO why are there 2 rows of `1` and 4 rows of `2`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff the usecase to achieve an opzimized list that best fits the scenario and in this case its the building up of these (2 + 1) combinations which gives an optimized output. Hope that makes sense,

Comment: @Larnu sorry for being very abstract but i hope you can undersatnd the question better now after the edit.

Comment: If you cannot define the logic to be used, then it cannot be done using sql server (or in any programming language). Perhaps there is a positional assumption in your description - but rows in a table have no inherent order by definition so that assumption cannot be applied to sorting without columns to support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ROWS` is exactly the number of rows with a paticular `ID`,
order the rows first by a group according to ROWS interval `(4),(1..2), (all the rest)` then within the second group row_number() sequences of `ID`s having `ROWS` = `1` and `2` independently. Within the same sequence number order by `ROWS` reverse order.

```
select ID, ROWS
from (
   select * 
     , case when ROWS = 4 then 1 
         when ROWS between 1 and 2 then 2
         else 3 end grp1
     , row_number() over(partition by ROWS order by ROWS) - row_number() over(partition by ROWS, ID order by ID) pos2
    from yourtable) t
order by grp1, case ROWS when 1 then pos2  else pos2/2 end, -ROWS, ID
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully. It was really tricky to get the order i wanted and i didnt think of creating the groups and positions this way. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can try doing it using order by clause. You can use your logic to sort values accordingly. Default order by ASC. So i have tried below query with order by if this gives you some idea of doing it:

```
select id from test order by case when id%2 = 0 then id end desc
```

Will give;

### ID

8

6

4

5

So you can try ordering with some logic inside.

Comment: I have already tried something similar to this, but i have not achived the order i need. I guess the logic is less of a problem, what im looking for is a way to actually move the rows according to the logic.